# Xcode / Objective-C Facebook Delegate Attempt

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to understand how a delegate works by using the Facebook SDK.

I have this as my view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "FacebookClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;

- (IBAction)btnPress:(id)sender;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize facebook;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FacebookClass *delegate = [[FacebookClass alloc] init];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"228051460617035" andDelegate:delegate];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)btnPress:(id)sender {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

...and other default viewcontroller methods
```

Then in my FacebookClass ..which I want to use as the delegate...I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface FacebookClass : NSObject
<UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>

@end
#import "FacebookClass.h"

@implementation FacebookClass

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"Logged in");
}

- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken
               expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt {

    NSLog(@"Extended it");
}

- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
{
    NSLog(@"Did not login");

}

- (void)fbDidLogout
{
    NSLog(@"Logged out");

}

- (void)fbSessionInvalidated
{
    NSLog(@"Session not valid");

}

@end
```

So what I want to happen is for when I log in, I want it to log the string "Logged in" in the console. As of now, it doesn't. Clearly, I'm confused.

**Update:
Added delegate instantiation.**

Answer (score 0):

Your object FBDelegate is nil. It is never instanced. You should in your

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

method instance it doing:

```
FBDelegate = [[FacebookClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Wait, what? Your first sentence is fine, but your code makes no sense.

Comment: you should declare the instanced delegate as class property.